# Which compression types support chunking in dask?

Tags: dask

When processing a large single file, it can be broken up as so:

```
import dask.bag as db

my_file = db.read_text('filename', blocksize=int(1e7))
```

This works great, but the files I'm working with have a high level of redundancy and so we keep them compressed. Passing in compressed gzip files gives an error that seeking in gzip isn't supported and so it can't be read in blocks.

The documentation here http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/bytes.html#compression suggests that some formats support random access.

The relevant internal code I think is here:

https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/bytes/compression.py#L47

It looks like lzma might support it, but it's been commented out.

Adding lzma into the seekable_files dict like in the commented out code:

```
from dask.bytes.compression import seekable_files
import lzmaffi
seekable_files['xz'] = lzmaffi.LZMAFile
data = db.read_text('myfile.jsonl.lzma', blocksize=int(1e7), compression='xz')
```

Throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = bag.read_text('myfile.jsonl.lzma', blocksize=int(1e7), compression='xz')
  File "condadir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/bag/text.py", line 80, in read_text
    **(storage_options or {}))
  File "condadir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 162, in read_bytes
    size = fs.logical_size(path, compression)
  File "condadir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 500, in logical_size
    g.seek(0, 2)
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

I assume that the functions at the bottom of the file (`get_xz_blocks`) for example can be used for this, but don't seem to be in use anywhere in the dask project.

Are there compression libraries that do support this seeking and chunking? If so, how can they be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right that the xz format can be useful to you. The confusion is, that the file may be block-formatted, but the standard implementation `lzmaffi.LZMAFile` (or lzma) does not make use of this blocking. Note that block-formatting is only optional for zx files, e.g., by using `--block-size=size` with xz-utils.

The function `compression.get_xz_blocks` will give you the set of blocks in a file by reading the header only, rather than the whole file, and you could use this in combination with delayed, essentially repeating some of the logic in `read_text`. We have not put in the time to make this seamless; the same pattern could be used to write blocked xz files too.